# Receiving notification in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing one application and in that I received notification. Notification shows current location and some location ,here I am getting *IllegaleArgumentException* on openNotification.

Below is my code :

```
 public class ShowMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

     GoogleMap _googleMap;


    LocationManager locationManger;
    TextView addressTextView,cTimeTextView;

     GcmIntentService serv;
     Context mContext;

     private LatLng jamPositions;
     private LatLng myCurrentPosition;
        private double ctim;
        private String adr;
        private double jamLatitude;
        private double jamLngitute;

        JsonParserForNotification Jsonparser;
        NotificationMapDetatilsDTO details;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    serv=new GcmIntentService();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_map);

    // Get parse data For Notification
    Jsonparser = new JsonParserForNotification();
    details = new NotificationMapDetatilsDTO();

    addressTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addressId);
    cTimeTextView   = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ctimeId);
    Intent noticeIntent = getIntent();
    String message = noticeIntent.getExtras().getString("message");

    NotificationMapDetatilsDTO notDetails=Jsonparser.Parser(message);
    jamLatitude=notDetails.getLat();
    jamLngitute = notDetails.getLng();
    adr = notDetails.getAddr();
    ctim = notDetails.getCtime();
    Log.e("LATSHOW", ""+jamLatitude);
    Log.e("LNGSHOW", ""+jamLngitute);
    Log.e("CTIMESHOW", ""+ctim);
    Log.e("ADDSHOW", adr);
    addressTextView.setText(adr);
    cTimeTextView.setText(""+ctim);
    int status = 
   GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
         int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();
    }
    else{
        _googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap(); 
        _googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        _googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        _googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        LocationManager service = 
         (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean enableGPS = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean enableWiFi= service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = service.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        //Location location = service.getLastKnownLocation(provider);



        service.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, this);
    }


    /*if(!enableGPS || !enableWiFi){
        Toast.makeText(ShowMapActivity.this, "GPS signal not found", 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/

    //locationManger = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);




    if(_googleMap==null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Map Not Available", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.show_map, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //locationManger.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, 
             this);
    if(location!=null){
        _googleMap.clear();
        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLangitude = location.getLongitude();


        myCurrentPosition = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLangitude);
        jamPositions =new LatLng(jamLatitude, jamLngitute);

        // Show  Current Location


   _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCurrentPosition,10)); 
        _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myCurrentPosition)
                                                .title("start"));

        // Shows Jam Locations
          _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(jamPositions,10)); 

         _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(jamPositions)
                                                 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                                 .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                                                 .flat(true));
    }
    // Getting Routes From Current Location TO Jam Location
    getRoutes();

    }


@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void getRoutes(){

    GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();

    org.w3c.dom.Document doc = md.getDocument(myCurrentPosition, jamPositions,    
     GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
    int distanceTime = md.getDistanceValue(doc);
    int durationTime = md.getDurationValue(doc);
    /*String startAddress = md.getStartAddress(doc);
    String endAddress = md.getEndAddress(doc);*/
    Log.e("DISTANCE",""+distanceTime);
    Log.e("DURATION",""+durationTime);

    if(durationTime/60 < ctim){

    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);


    for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
    rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));

    }

    _googleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
    }   

}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();

_googleMap.clear();
}

 }
```

LogCat Error Trace:

```
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.technowellServices.traffic/com.technowellServices.traffic.ShowMapActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1728)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1747)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:476)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at com.technowellServices.traffic.ShowMapActivity.onCreate(ShowMapActivity.java:121)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
03-12 16:22:18.484: E/AndroidRuntime(3000):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1692)
```

Comment: i atteched with my code

Comment: Check line 121 of ShowMapActivity.java class.

Comment: service.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 0, 0, ShowMapActivity.this); but herre provider gets null

Comment: i dont know what happing there

Comment: Is it require handle Exception while create provider ??

Comment: Yes definately,because if you have zero providers then there will exception always.

Comment: Its good practice to handle exceptions in code.

Comment: But in map not shows any marker

Comment: You mean after implementing the code for provider?

Comment: Yes i handle Exception then it show map but not coming markers

Comment: It might be the minor issue of some code. But do you receive notification now?

Comment: Yes i received and show map also after open notification

Comment: But still i have problem

Comment: In which line, you have set your marker?

Comment: What is this??? I cannot see line numbers. :)

Comment: _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCurrentPosition,10)); 
        _googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myCurrentPosition)
                                                .title("start"));

Comment: in onLocationChanged() method see once that method

Comment: The problem is provider we can caught IlligleArgumentException but the code process stop there .

Comment: if we handle provider the code works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example :

[Android Location example.](http://www.androidadb.com/class/android/location/Criteria.java.html)

You need to check whether "provider" is null or not.
If yes, then you need to get the list of providers first.

Hope this answers your question.